# Gradle DSL meaning for it.name

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build, dsl

What does `it.name` mean?  Is it generated, or can the values be specified?  Is `it` like `this`, refers to the *current object*?

```
 jar.doFirst
 {
     // aggregate all the jars needed at runtime into a local variable (array)
     def manifestClasspath = configurations.runtime.collect { it.name }

     // remove duplicate jar names, and join the array into a single string
     manifestClasspath = manifestClasspath.unique().join(" ")

     // set manifest attributes - mainClassName must be set before it is used here
     manifest.attributes.put("Main-Class", mainClassName)
     manifest.attributes.put("Class-Path", manifestClasspath)
 }
```

This method will execute before the `jar` task?

see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736602/262852

Comment: `it` is the implicit variable (and shorthand) for iterator. Do note that `it` is from groovy and is not added by Gradle DSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**

`it` is the implicit parameter for Groovy's closures.

```
configurations.runtime.collect { it.name }
```

is equivalent to

```
configurations.runtime.collect { it -> it.name }
```

`name` is simply a property. For more information about `it` look [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#implicit-it).

**2.**

Yes, it will be executed before jar task. It's a part of the API, look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) in section 14.7 for example